# Track who did what using digital signatures

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

Currently I'm working with Hyperledger Fabric. I want to track info who submitted a transaction. Is there someone who can help my with this problem ? Who can tell what should i do?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried? What are you planning to do? Can you provide more details? By "who", do you mean you want to track a person IRL? Are you OK having a logical representation of this "who" in your blockchain? Do you mean track actual people, or certifiates delivered by your CA?

Comment: Florian Castelain, it's my mistake, I mean track the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad.

You could have find the answer very easily by checking the shim documentation (the following ling is for nodejs shim. You may find the golang equivalent I beleive):

https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html#getX509Certificate__anchor